# I cannot access the functions that are defined in the wsdl file.The code and the error snippet is provided

Tags: node.js, soap, wsdl

I am not able to access the ResloveIP function defined in the wsdl file. I checked the service using SoapUI and it's working fine. Please help!

```
var soap=require('soap');
var url='http://ws.cdyne.com/ip2geo/ip2geo.asmx?wsdl';

soap.createClient(url, function(err, client) {
    if(err){
      console.log(err);
      return;
    }
    //console.log(client.describe());
    client.IP2Geo.IP2GeoSoap.ResolveIP('184.172.104.38');//the ResolveIP function cannot be accessed.
});
```

**Error message:**

[image]

Comment: The problem is solved.

Comment: how, share solution

Comment: @maddy you will have to add one more parameter in the ResolveIP function, that is client.IP2Geo.IP2GeoSoap.ResolveIP({ipAddress:"184.172.104.38",licenseKey:"?"}, function(err, result){   console.log(err);   console.log(result); });